# AngularJS lazyload routing is not working properly

Tags: angularjs, routes

Can someone help me with this routing? It always gives the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

The code in question:

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad','ngRoute', 'commonApp', 'adminApp', 'ui.bootstrap', 'gm', 'ngMessages', 'daterangepicker','customDirectives', 'mw-datepicker-range','uiGmapgoogle-maps','ngAutocomplete','ngImageCompress']);

app.config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider' , function($ocLazyLoadProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

//Config For ocLazyLoading
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
    'debug': true, // For debugging 'true/false'
    'events': true, // For Event 'true/false'
    'modules': [{ // Set modules initially
        name : 'home', // State1 module
        files: ['home/home.controller.js',
                'home/home.service.js',
                'home/homeMapper.service.js',

                ]
    },{
        name : 'about', // State2 module
        files: ['about/about.controller.js']
    }]
});

//Config/states of UI Router
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: "/home",
    views : {
        "" : {
            templateUrl:"/home/home.html"
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load('home'); // Resolve promise and load before view 
        }]
    }
})
.state('about', {
    url: "/about",
    views : {
        "" : {
            templateUrl:"/about/about.html"
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load('about'); // Resolve promise and load before view 
        }]
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: I have formatted your error message and code for you. Please pay attention to your question layout so that other users can understand your question better.

Comment: where I have to check for your formatted docs?

Comment: The error `[$injector:modulerr]` suggests that some module was not found, one or many of these dependencies are not present at the time of loading your file. `['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad','ngRoute', 'commonApp', 'adminApp', 'ui.bootstrap', 'gm', 'ngMessages', 'daterangepicker','customDirectives', 'mw-datepicker-range','uiGmapgoogle-maps','ngAutocomplete','ngImageCompress']`, please confirm that all of these dependencies are present before you execute this file.